# How to exclude file from Code Smells in SonarQube?

Tags: java, android, sonarqube

I am working in Code smells in my project, but here is one class in which i don't want to change anything. This class showing in code smells, I want it should not be show in Code smells.

Using This Property to Exclude that class but didn't work for me

```
property "sonar.exclusions", "**/*LineChart.java"
```

Can anyone please help me on this. How can i exclude this class from Code smells

Comment: can you post your build.gradle

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing same issue, sonar.exclusions not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your class file is in sub package.
This should work:

- property "sonar.exclusions", "**/**/*LineChart.java"